# Learning Common Lisp tips for a Windows/C++ programmer

Tags: emacs, lisp, slime

I'm an experienced C++/.NET/Java Windows/web programmer trying to learn (Common) Lisp. I'm reading [Practical Common Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_Common_Lisp) and using [SLIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLIME).

I'm getting the Lisp language easily enough, but I'm having trouble groking the mechanics of development. One of my issues is dealing with Emacs. I have no experience with it and find it generally confusing with hard to find/figure out commands.

Specific questions:

- I get the [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop), but I don't quite get how I can use it effectively. When I need to change a function I have to retype the defun and make changes (tedious and error prone). How can I do this better?
- How do I get from entering code at the REPL to actually having a program? I'm used to the C model where you have code files that you can review, edit and recompile. I know Lisp has something similar (via the load function), but how does one get a function I just defined and tested into a file to be saved? I'm hoping there's a better method than my current select+copy+paste.
- How do you debug errors? Is there any ability to step into code like I would with other languages?
- As long as the S-expression is valid, I don't get any errors when entering a `(defun ...)`. It's not until I try to use it that I find out it's not valid. Is there any way to get errors sooner (i.e. compile the code)?
- Is there some IDE that would be more familiar to me or allow me to play with the language easier?
- Should I switch to learning [Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29) instead?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might also want to look into Clojure; it's a lisp that operates on the JVM and has nice interop. with Java. I've not worked with it yet, but have watched a few lectures on it, and it looks nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> -I get the REPL, but don't quite get how I can use it effectively. When I
>   need to change a function I have to
>   retype the defun and make changes
>   (tedious and error prone). How can I
>   do this better?
>
> -How do I get from entering code at the REPL to actually having a program?
>   I'm used to the C model where you have
>   code files that you can review, edit
>   and recompile. I know lisp has
>   something similar (via the load
>   function), but how does one get a
>   function I just defined and tested
>   into a file to be saved? I'm hoping
>   there's a better method than my
>   current select+copy+paste.

Load SLIME. Enter code in your `.lisp` file, and then run `slime-eval-buffer` to load all your code into Lisp. Then, for a specific function you are hacking on C-e, C-j to redefine it in your running Lisp.

> -How do you debug errors? Is there any ability to step into code like I would with other languages?

Yes. (`trace 'my-function`) - or some variant on that - and when `my-function` is called, it will break into the debugger.

> -As long as the S-expression is valid, I don't get any errors when entering a
>   (defun ...). It's not until I try to
>   use it that I find out it's not valid.
>   Is there any way to get errors sooner
>   (i.e. compile the code)?

To some degree, that is a characteristic of dynamic languages (Python, Perl, Ruby, Lisp, etc.). Try [SBCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel_Bank_Common_Lisp) for better error-checking.

> -Is there some IDE that would be more familiar to me or allow me to play with the language easier?

Emacs is *the* free IDE for Lisp. Allegro has a free edition I believe; I've never tried it though..

> -Should I switch to learning Scheme instead?

Nah, Scheme is not as pragmatic a language.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm an experienced C++/.NET/Java Windows/Web programmer trying to learn (Common) Lisp. I'm reading Practical Common Lisp and using SLIME.

One can also use the [LispWorks Personal Edition](http://www.lispworks.com/downloads/) for learning Lisp. It has some limitations and the full product is commercial, but it is quite a bit easier to use.

> I get the REPL, but don't quite get how I can use it effectively. When I need to change a function I have to retype the defun and make changes (tedious and error prone). How can I do this better?

The REPL has a history. With keyboard commands you can get back prior input and change it. Other than that just edit a Lisp file and compile code from there. In Lisp you can compile/eval individual expressions and definitions. Typical IDEs like SLIME, [LispWorks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LispWorks) or [Allegro CL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegro_Common_Lisp) allow you to run code also from normal Lisp text windows - additionally to executing expressions in the REPLA (aka Listener).

> How do I get from entering code at the REPL to actually having a program? I'm used to the C model where you have code files that you can review, edit and recompile. I know Lisp has something similar (via the load function), but how does one get a function I just defined and tested into a file to be saved? I'm hoping there's a better method than my current select+copy+paste.

Copy and paste in one thing. But the correct way is to work from a text file in an editor window. One can compile/load expressions, the editor buffer or the associated file.

> How do you debug errors? Is there any ability to step into code like I would with other languages?

See STEP, TRACE and related. SLIME, LispWorks and Allegro CL have lots of additional features.

> As long as the S-expression is valid, I don't get any errors when entering a (defun ...). It's not until I try to use it that I find out it's not valid. Is there any way to get errors sooner (i.e. compile the code)?

For many cases one uses a compiler. The compiler will find a range of errors and also will note when something is unusual (for example a function does not exist or a variable has not been defined).

-Is there some IDE that would be more familiar to me or allow me to play with the language easier?

LispWorks, Allegro CL are the best under Windows. There are some alternatives like [Corman Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corman_Common_Lisp) (I don't know it is maintained right now) or even Ufasoft Lisp.

> Should I switch to learning Scheme instead?

Not really.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like you're really using SLIME, or at least not in the way it was intended to be used.  ("have to retype the defun", "the C model where you have code files")

I recommend watching some SLIME screencasts (or, even better, watching a Lisp programmer use SLIME for a few minutes, if you have one handy).  The [SLIME webpage has a couple](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/#documentation).

Comment: Thanks, I definitely think a tutorial about SLIME will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you'd really enjoy the DrRacket IDE. [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) is closer to Scheme than to Common Lisp, but you could dip your toes into the Lisp family without the speed bump of the Emacs style of development.

Comment: This sounds interesting to me. I'll take a look at this language/IDE.